# Too Few Parameters : Expected 1 performing SELECT INTO

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using VBA I'm trying to perform a SELECT INTO following the documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx

I'm attempting to select from a query and insert into a new table:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [BookingDate], [StartTime], [first_name], [last_name] INTO [NewTable] FROM myQuery"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

However it's throwing an error

> Too Few Parameters : Expected 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This typically indicates a misspelled or missing field name.

Comment: I tried 

strSQL = "SELECT * INTO [NewTable] FROM myQuery"

 to start with but was getting exactly the same error.

Comment: Then your query needs a parameter. If you filter on a form field, that will be the case.

Comment: Hmm my query uses [TempVars]... which is populated

Comment: Try to remove them for a test. If that runs, you must find other methods to apply the values from your TempVars.

Comment: Removing tempvars seemed to resolve that problem(not that it doesn't create other problems elsewhere...) only to be presented with BookingDate  could refer to more than one table.  Prefixing it with the query name (the one and only source!) didn't help.  Alas that's another question.  Thanks for your help.  Access really is an abomination!

Comment: Andre's solution using DoCmd provided the answer which allows usage of TempVar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From
https://books.google.de/books?id=JgBe3OMEoU8C&lpg=PA517&ots=hm-yKG68cy&dq=Db.Execute%20tempvars&pg=PA517#v=onepage&q&f=true

> **Caution**
>
> The TempVar scope is defined by the Application object, which includes any of its children such as forms, reports, and queries.
>
> The database engine, however, is outside of the application scope. [...]
>
> Also if you use the `CurrentDb` object to execute a query, that query will run outside of the application scope. Instead, use `DoCmd.OpenQuery` to execute the query and it will have access to your TempVars.

Or alternatively, `DoCmd.RunSQL` see http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1949829

Comment: Thanks Andre I'll give that a go

Comment: Just to confirm the answer - DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL) seems to work with the TempVars.  OpenQuery suggested by the book I think is more for selecting from queries.  Thanks!

Comment: `CurrentDb.Execute("select table_.* into table from table_")` works for me in one database, but doesn't work in another. Though it says `Too Few Parameters : Expected 2` instead of "1".

Comment: Please ask a new question with all details. @Winand